# Getting weird results when attaching the same respone to multiple listeners

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I'm attaching a single `submit()` to a button and the enter key. On a fresh page they both attach and respond normally running `submit()` a single time. The issue arises ***only*** after the click event has run, then the keypress event starts running `submit()` two times thereafter instead of once, while the click continues to respond normally.

I feel like I've done this before and solved it (or just missed) after implementing a `getSubmit()` with some `if()`'s or returning something but I feel like this should work.

```
var bindCtrlr = (function() {

    var submit = () => console.log('hi')

    document.querySelector('.add__btn').addEventListener('click', submit, false)

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
            submit()
        }
    }, false)

})()
```

The `submit()` should ***always*** run a single time when `.add__btn` is clicked or the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is firing twice is because the button click event triggers also on enter. But it only triggers twice if the focus is still on the button after you click it. When the focus is not on the button it only fires once. Hope this will help you.